# Network authentication using router firmware scripting

Tags: authentication, network, wifi, router

To connect to internet in our institute, you need to login with your credentials on a page and then approve the IP address for proxy less usage. On a router, if one device authenticates, all the other devices also get authenticated. So I want to know if I can authenticate from my router periodically.

Comment: I suggested some re-wording in braces that may make your question less ambiguous.  I'm not sure if this is proper use of editing or I should have used the comments for the rewording, instead of the edit functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are behind a NAT router where all connected devices get the same outgoing IP address and if the authorization against this specific site is solely done by IP address then it is enough that a single internal device behind the router will authorize itself against the external server because all internal devices share the same externally visible IP address.

This means that you don't need to run something on the router itself to automatize the authorization, but that you can run this on any of the internal devices. How this authorization can be automated exactly depends on how the authorization is done usually - and such information are missing from your question. But if it is just visiting some site and entering username and password then there are lots of command line clients or scripting languages which will help you there. But the exact details would be out of scope of this site, because they are just web site automatization and not really related to security.